# How can I use shortcut keys for context menu items?

Tags: keyboard

A common workflow on a Windows or Linux PC is to right click on a link in (say) Chrome, then hit "L" to copy the URL to the clipboard.

How can I achieve this on MacOS?  I don't want to have to use the mouse to select the relevant menu item.

Answer (score 2):

Context menus can be navigated in Safari with keyboard shortcuts. E.g pressing C - Enter will jump to copy link.

Comment: hmm.  Extra keypress ;-) Doesn't seme to work in Chrome anyway. Thanks.

Comment: It works for me in Chrome (beta channel) under Lion. It works in all Cocoa apps.

I have to admit though, the implementation is a bit hit and miss and not every command has a keystroke.

Answer (score 1):

This free app

http://www.macupdate.com/app/mac/21559/shortcuts

Might help.